# Gridview pagination not working when the gridview is created dynamically by dropdownlist list selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have cached a select * query in a dataset in c#.

On my page I have 3 dropdownlists.
Depending on the dropdownlist selected I filter the datatable and bind it to the gridview.
whenever the data in the dropdownlist gets changed,I display the data accordingly.

My problem is, I have added pagination to this gridview since I have more than 500 results for each query. 
When I try to paginate,the gridview disappears.The value in the dropdownlist does not change.

what should I do?

the code for page Index changing of gridview is:

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

thank you for you help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your grid again in the function

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    //provide data source here
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps that may help you out...

1. Add dynamic gridview control to page or in any other control where u want to show it on page.
2. Set its pager settings along with `PageIndexChanging` Event Handler
3. Call it in `OnInit` Event instead of `Page_Load`

Following is sample code:

```
private void AddGridDynamically() 
{
    try
    {
        HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell td = new HtmlTableCell();
        GridView gv = new GridView();                                
            gv.AllowPaging = true;
            gv.PageSize = 20;
            gv.PagerSettings.Visible = true;
            gv.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.NumericFirstLast;
            gv.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(gv_PageIndexChanging);

        FillGrid(gv);

        td.Controls.Add(gv);
        tr.Cells.Add(td);
        tbl1.Rows.Add(tr);

        gv.EmptyDataText="No Data Found";
        gv.DataBind();        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }       
}

private void FillGrid(GridView gv)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        DataRow dr;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "AnyThing" + i;
            dr[1] = i;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        }
        gv.DataSource = dt;          
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
    }
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    AddGridDynamically();
}
```